# UIActionSheet and Twitter username selection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, twitter

I'm trying to implement a way for users to pick from the Twitter accounts they've set up on the iPhone (iOS5 and up). I can get the usernames to appear in a UIActionSheet, but for some reason the UIActionSheet takes about 5 seconds to appear after the method has been called.

I thought perhaps it was because it took a while to retrieve the list of Twitter accounts, but in my log they appear instantly, so it's not that.

Any ideas?

```
- (void)TwitterSwitch {
    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

// Create an account type that ensures Twitter accounts are retrieved.
    ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

    NSMutableArray *buttonsArray = [NSMutableArray array];

// Request access from the user to use their Twitter accounts.
    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {


       // Get the list of Twitter accounts.
        NSArray *accountsArray = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

       NSLog(@"%@", accountsArray);


       [accountsArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

           [buttonsArray addObject:((ACAccount*)obj).username];
        }];


       NSLog(@"%@", buttonsArray);

        UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
        for( NSString *title in buttonsArray)
            [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:title];
        [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
        actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex = actionSheet.numberOfButtons-1;
        [actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
}]; 

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem might be that in requestAccessToAccountsWithType:withCompletionHandler: the handler can be called on an arbitrary queue, and you're showing a UI element (the action sheet) from within that handler. Since interaction with the UI should only be done on the main thread, that could be a problem.  I tried moving some of the code into another method, and calling it on the main thread -- this was much faster:

```
- (void)TwitterSwitch {
    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

    // Create an account type that ensures Twitter accounts are retrieved.
    ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];


    // Request access from the user to use their Twitter accounts.
    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {


        // Get the list of Twitter accounts.
        NSArray *accountsArray = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

        NSLog(@"%@", accountsArray);
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(populateSheetAndShow:) withObject:accountsArray waitUntilDone:NO];
        }];
}

-(void)populateSheetAndShow:(NSArray *) accountsArray {
    NSMutableArray *buttonsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    [accountsArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

            [buttonsArray addObject:((ACAccount*)obj).username];
        }];


        NSLog(@"%@", buttonsArray);

        UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
        for( NSString *title in buttonsArray)
            [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:title];
        [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
        actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex = actionSheet.numberOfButtons-1;
        [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}
```

Note that I changed the way I show the sheet because in my test app I didn't have a tab bar controller.

Comment: I can't test this, but I don't think there's any need for the enumerateObjectsUsingBlock method or the buttonsArray. In your for-in loop you can just loop through accounts array (ACAccount *account in accountsArray) and then addButtonWithTitle:account.username.

Comment: Works very nicely, including your suggestion to get rid of the enumerateObjectsUsingBlock and buttonsArray. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, how would I go about limiting the size of the actionSheet array to the first 5 accounts? I'm worried that if a user has a bunch of Twitter accounts, it could mess up the actionSheet.

Comment: Well, first you would have to decide what you mean by "first 5".  If you just want the first 5 that come up, then just add a counter variable in you for-in loop, and when it reaches 5, exit the loop with a break command.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use multi-threading to speed up your tasks. Here's how you can do it:

```
dispatch_queue_t twitterAccounts = dispatch_queue_create("DisplayTwitterAccounts", NULL);
    dispatch_async(twitterAccounts, ^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //Your Code goes here
        });
    });
dispatch_release(twitterAccounts);
```

Take note of the dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()): This is because UIKit calls can only happen in the main thread. (Ref.: Stanford CS193P course slide).

"DisplayTwitterAccounts" is just the name of the queue, so that you can look for it in the debugger/console.

Comment: What line would I use to setup the `twitterAccounts` variable?